# Showing steps of a calculation p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Im making a sketch to show sorting algorithms. The algorithm itself works, but when I execute it, it goes directly into the solved state, while I want it to show all calculations. I have tried setting the framerate a bit lower, but that just delays the visuals. How would I set this up so it executes the `drawRect()` function after every calculation?
Here is my code:

```
let elements = 25
var array = []
let goal = []
let tempAr = []
let i = 1
let sorted = false

function setup() {
    // frameRate(5)
    // put setup code here
    createCanvas(600, 600)
    background(25)
    // make the goal array ascending
    while (goal.length < elements) {
        goal.push(i)
        i++
    }
    // make the scrambled array
    i = 0
    tempAr = goal
    while (i < elements) {
        let rng = Math.floor(random(tempAr.length))
        array.push(tempAr[rng])
        tempAr.splice(rng, 1)
        i++
    }
}

function draw() {
    fill('#f1f442')
    drawRect()
    if (!sorted) {
        mysort()
    }
}
function drawRect() {
    i = 1
    while (i <= elements) {
        rect(i * (width / elements) - (width / elements), height - array[i - 1] * height / elements, width / elements, array[i - 1] * height / elements)
        i++
    }
}
async function mysort() {
    sorted = false
    while (!sorted) {
        sorted = true
        var e = 0
        while (e < array.length) {
            if (array[e] > array[e + 1]) {
                clear()
                background(25)
                let temp = array[e + 1]
                array[e + 1] = array[e]
                array[e] = temp
                sorted = false
            }
            e++
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55310038/1978785

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In P5 everything that happens in `setup()` happens right away, `draw()` gets called after that and it gets continuously called at @60fps (or whatever you have the frame rate set at). If you want to show the progress of your algorithm, do one iteration (or however many needed to give the desired output) of your algorithm per `draw()` call.

Comment: One way could be to save the state of the array after each iteration of the ```while ``` loop in the ```mySort``` function in another array like ```history``` for example. Then in ```draw``` , use the saved states to draw the rectangles.